# Sort a list of lists based on alphabetical order of inner list elements in Mahtematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of lists with inner lists possibly of variable lengths. I need to sort the outer list based on the alphabetical order of the inner list elements. For example, given a list of

`{{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 10, 0}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}}`

I want the output after `Sort` to be

`{{0, 0, 10, 0}, {0, 0, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {5, 1, 2}}`

I just do not know how to handle the variable lengths of inner lists in order to write a comparison function. Please help.

**Edit**

BTW, the original list is a numerical one.

**Edit 2**

For example, I have a list:

> {{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 11, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 12}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}}

The output should be:

> {{0, 0, 1, 12}, {0, 0, 11, 0}, {0, 0, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {5, 1, 2}}

The reason is that `1` is lexically less than `11`, which is less than `7`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Does my edit 2 address your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up a [lexciographic comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) like this:

```
lexComp[_, {}] := False;
lexComp[{}, _] := True;
lexComp[{a_, as___}, {b_, bs___}] := a < b || a == b && lexComp[{as}, {bs}];
```

You can then sort using that to get the desired effect:

```
Sort[{{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 10, 0}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}}, lexComp]

{{0, 0, 7}, {0, 0, 10, 0}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {5, 1, 2}}
```

If you wish to treat the numbers as strings in your sorting, you can modify it like so:

```
lessAsString[a_, b_] := Order @@ (ToString /@ {a, b}) === 1;

olexComp[_, {}] := False;
olexComp[{}, _] := True;
olexComp[{a_, as___}, {b_, bs___}] := lessAsString[a, b] || a === b && olexComp[{as}, {bs}];
```

Here is the example of such a sort:

```
In[5]:= Sort[{{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 11, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 12}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}}, olexComp]

Out[5]= {{0, 0, 1, 12}, {0, 0, 11, 0}, {0, 0, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {5, 1, 2}}
```

Comment: shouldn't {0, 0, 10, 0} precedes {0, 0, 7}?

Comment: @QiangLi: If you want each number treated as text, then yes. Is this what you desire?

Comment: @Sebastian I was just playing around with Sort[list,p] like your example. Looks like there is some weirdness with Mathematica's sorting behavior on Strings -- try `Ordering[{"{1,11,2}", "{1,1,2}"}]` and `Ordering[{"{1,11}", "{1,1}"}]` -- they are not the same.  @Qiang -- if you want more complicated lexical ordering, use Sebastian's example example as a template.

Comment: @QiangLi: Perhaps this version better suits your needs.

Comment: choose as correct answer since it shows how to customize the comparator so that I can use it in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
alphaSort = #[[ Ordering @ Map[ToString, PadRight@#, {2}] ]] &;
```

This works by preparing the data for the default `Ordering` sort, and then using that order to sort the original list.

In this case, padding all of the lists to the same length keeps this `Sort` property from interfering:

> Sort usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth-first manner.

`ToString` is used to get an alphabetical order rather than a numeric one.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
{{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 10, 0}, {0, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 
   6, 1, 4}} // SortBy[#, ToString] &
```

This works because lexically, comma and space precede the numbers, so {a,b} is lexically before {a,b,c}.

Comment: I see. I was initially thinking along the line of `Sort`, first directly using `ToString`, in this case wrong, I need `Apply[StringJoin, Map[#, ToString]]&`... And I was stuck. So what is good about `SortBy` not shared by `Sort`?

Comment: @Qiang Li -- `SortBy` lets you sort a list without transforming it.  As an alternative you could call `ToString` on each element of your list, sort the resulting strings, and then call `ToExpression` on each element of the sorted list to recover the vectors of Integers.  That's much less efficient.  Another method would be call `ToString` on each element of your list, then call `Ordering` on the resulting list, and use `Take` to permute the original list to sorted order.  I use this trick a lot to generate and cache permutations without copying the original list(s).

Comment: actually your answer is wrong! try this example: `{{0, 0, 7}, {5, 0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 11, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 12}, {0, 6, 2}, {5,
   1, 2}, {0, 3, 6, 1, 4}}`. Here I expect `{0, 0, 1, 12}` to precede `{0, 0, 11, 0}`